# Confusing position for the buttons

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-deferred, design

Is it a reason to have the same style for the buttons on a page? Also, it is the best position of the buttons in the section where you can add comments and answers?

Maybe is just me, but I always press the "Add Another Answer" button instead "Add Comment".

I really like to see a change for the UI in this section. What do you think?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you just press `Enter` after writing a comment?

Comment: Enter on desktop is not submit.

Comment: In comment field? Actually it is and I'm submitting this comment by pressing Enter on desktop. Seems like you are using some extension or userscript to allow Enter in this field.

Comment: Not really... I don't use any extension for fields.

Answer (score 1):

> **Note:** I am a Senior Product Designer at Stack Overflow

You are not the first person to point this out. This is something we've wanted to address for a while, unfortunately this particular project has two problems:

1. It's a low priority for the development team.
2. The code surrounding commenting is a confusing tangled mess and would probably need re-written.

This doesn't excuse the inconsistency though, and I appreciate you bringing to our attention. Hearing from communities helps us know what people are struggling with.